# Range of HSV values to sample an Image as done by adobe

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, photoshop

I have an image as shown in the inset. I sampled it in Adobe Photoshop using the blue color as the image shows. The sampled image is shown in gray-scale on the left.

I know that openCV provides a similar method to sample images that is the `inRange()` function. How can I find out the range of HSV values that Adobe checked for to sample my image. Since the resultant image is pretty much what I want and I am not able to determine the range myself It would be a great help if some one could guide me for the same.

[image: Photoshop Sampled]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your image in HSV with `cv::cvtColor(...)` [here the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvtcolor#void%20cvtColor%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20code,%20int%20dstCn%29)

Then accordingly to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) the blue is near to 240° of the HUE channel of your image.
You can set something like `maxHue = 270` and a `minHue = 180` or other values to scan your image.

Maybe you should set a `minSaturation` and a `minValue` to avoid the black and white.

To find the best ranges you can link them with some sliders in a Qt GUI and change them until you get the same result as photoshop...

Comment: In openCV Hue values only range between 0 to 180 :)
That slider idea is good.

Comment: Oh yes, you have to divide the values by 2!

Comment: I am still not able to quite nail it even after experiments.

Comment: try to put your results and how you get them in the question, maybe looking at the differences can help

Comment: The problem is even if I get the correct result it varies for another image since I'm sampling frames from a video sequence. But Photoshop does it for all frames evidently.

Comment: maybe the parameters changes dynamically with overall evaluation of the frame... with lights or something else. But I'm not sure on this.